How to fix CORS issues in CircleCI API version 1
I am using CircleCI API v1 and am trying to access the endpoint
https://circleci.com/docs/api/v1/index.html#recent-jobs-for-a-single-project
in my React script but keep getting CORS errors like "CORS Missing Allow Origin" in Firefox Developer edition or "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." in Opera
I can get it to work using https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/corsdemo but is there a better way of doing things for production?

turns out i needed to put a forward slash '/' at the end of each call otherwise they fail
